# 4 deep level folder not working "../../../../config.js" in vue component

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am trying to export `config.js` and import it from `Allplayer.vue` but when I call it, it's say it was not a function.

how to fix this? Is there problem when module is in 4 deep level of folder structure? 
Because other component can reach the `config.js` file in 3 deep level of folder from `config.js` file.

[image]

[image]

Comment: no, it should work, how do you export the config.js? did you use export default?  tell us more about your code snippet

Comment: Why are you importing something outside `/src` in the first place? I'd move the config file into a folder like `src/config` and that should work

Answer (score 0):

did you use named export and import it properly?

```
// something.js
export default something;

//another.vue
import somthing from "./something"
```

or

```
// something.js
export {
    something,
}

//another.vue
import { something } from "./something";
```

or you can use commonJS

```
// somthing.js
module.exports = somthing;

//another.vue
const somthing = require("./somthing");
```